# How to change time zone in PayPal?

Tags: paypal

This is the official answer from PayPal for this question:

> Log in to your PayPal account. Click Profile near the top of the page.
>   Click Settings. Click Update in the Time zone section. Select your
>   preferred time zone and click Save.

<sup>(https://www.paypal.com/c2/webapps/helpcenter/helphub/article/?solutionId=FAQ1669&topicID=&m=ARA)</sup>

From Profile page I click the link *My Settings*. On that page I don't see "time zone" mentioned anywhere. Here's the screen capture of the page I'm seeing:

[image: Screenshot of PayPal's Settings page]

Comment: I have the same problem, they don't have a fix for it at the moment.